# Dynamic Type on Smaller iPhones (4, 5, SE)

Tags: ios, text, fonts, uikit, accessibility

On https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/visual-design/typography/

It indicates that on a smaller iPhone SE, that Title2 is, for example, 20pts, not 22pts as on larger sizes.

However when I apply the Title2 style to a label in Xcode, and run on iPhone SE, it's 22pts, not 20pt as suggested by Apple's own style guide. Does anyone know why this is? I've tried enabling Dynamic Type.